# Query in SQL with sum and group

Tags: sql-server, group-by, sum, max

I want to select multiple data from multiple tables so I used join to get these data and from these data I want to have a group by of codes and have a total of all amount per codes that are group together. I tried using `SUM()` with `MAX()` and `GROUP BY` how ever I get wrong sum for each group.

My data result looks like these when no sum and max and group is involve:

**Query is:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
t17.acctcode,
(pcchrgamt)  
FROM 
hpatchrg AS t3 INNER JOIN 
hcharge AS t17 ON t3.chargcode = t17.chrgcode INNER JOIN
Codes AS t14 ON t17.uacs = t14.accCode

WHERE acctno = '2007-000025486'
```

**Result is:**

```
acctcode    pcchrgamt
613 RECORDS 56.00
613 RECORDS 60.00
631 CSR     56.00
631 CSR     60.00
631 CSR     74.00
631 CSR     88.40
643         2.00
643         3.00
643         4.00
643         6.00
643         8.75
643         10.00
643         11.40
643         39.75
643         40.00
643         41.60
643         44.00
643         47.10
643         49.00
643         50.50
643         80.00
643         80.50
643         88.00
643         96.00
643         100.00
643         106.35
643         109.95
643         132.00
643         192.00
643         878.50
643         2465.00
643         4930.00
```

When I put `SUM` and `MAX` and `GROUP BY`, the code looks like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
t17.acctcode AS acctcode,
SUM(pcchrgamt) AS pcchrgamt  
FROM 
hpatchrg AS t3 INNER JOIN 
hcharge AS t17 ON t3.chargcode = t17.chrgcode INNER JOIN 
Codes AS t14 ON t17.uacs = t14.accCode

WHERE acctno = '2007-000025486'  
GROUP BY acctcode
```

**Result is:**

```
acctcode    pcchrgamt
631 CSR         4454.40
613 RECORDS     1856.00
643             20813073.75
```

The grouping is correct but the sum is so off. I expect sum only to be like for `613 RECORDS` is `116.00` but it is way off. I also tried with Sub query but it gets error for now and I am still working on it.

I hope someone can point out what's wrong in the query.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At a glance, could `distinct` in the second query be processed after the `group by`?  Try moving it to a subquery:

```
SELECT  acctcode
,       SUM(pcchrgamt)
FROM    (
        SELECT  DISTINCT t17.acctcode
        ,       pcchrgamt
        FROM    hpatchrg AS t3
        JOIN    hcharge AS t17 ON t3.chargcode = t17.chrgcode
        JOIN    Codes AS t14 ON t17.uacs = t14.accCode
        WHERE   acctno = '2007-000025486'
        ) sub
GROUP BY
        acctcode
```

Comment: I just tried your code and i think i get the correct sum can you explain further i want to understand what you did and also what is `sub` will really help alot if there is abit of explanatio

Comment: This happens because `DISTINCT`is only applied after the `SUM`is calculated, and somewhere in your `JOINS` you get 16 matches

Comment: `sub` is the name of the subquery. It's not used, but required by SQL Server. Try to run your query with and without `distinct` to see the difference.

Comment: I wanted to up but it says I cant i just tick it for now and up it when i can explanation is appreciated.

Comment: @Manlapig: Looks like you need [15 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) to upvote